# Attribute by Code

Tags: magento2

i have product attribute in dropdown i want to get all option of that attribute how i get programtically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add to the constructor of your class an instance of \Magento\Eav\Model\Config like this:

```
protected $eavConfig;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    ...
}
```

then

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
$arr = [];
    foreach ($options as $option) {
      if ($option['value'] > 0) {
        $arr[] = $option;
      }
    }
```

Out put

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 280
            [label] => option1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 281
            [label] => option2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 282
            [label] => option3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => 283
            [label] => option4
        )
)
```

Which is better? Answer is below.

\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository
ultimately at end call 
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode);
You can judge by it which is better. :-)

1st call file : vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository.php method

```
public function get($attributeCode)
    {
        return $this->eavAttributeRepository->get(
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
            $attributeCode
        );
    }
```

2nd file call : vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\AttributeRepository.php

```
public function get($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeInterface $attribute */
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode);
        if (!$attribute || !$attribute->getAttributeId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                __(
                    'The attribute with a "%1" attributeCode doesn\'t exist. Verify the attribute and try again.',
                    $attributeCode
                )
            );
        }
        return $attribute;
    }
```

Comment: how get values Array ( [label] => [value] => ) Array ( [value] => 2608 [label] => LKD - 2NS Large )

Comment: i want attribute text value

Comment: @dfsd check updated answer.

Comment: \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,  its good or load from \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,

Comment: @dfsd check the updated answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Product Repository :-**

```
protected $productAttributeRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,
){
    $this->productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
}
```

**After This You Can Get Options Like This :-**

```
$options = $productAttributeRepository->get('attribute_code')->getOptions();
```